Edit count dropped suddenly
I had roughly 250 edits (which included tag wikis) listed as of last week.  I'm not sure when the number changed, but it dropped to 104 suddenly.
Was this a recent change?  Are tag wiki edits not counting towards Copy Editor (or even the regular edit count) anymore?
(I don't remember what everyone's totals were, but it seems as though counts dropped across the board)

I have edited tag wikis on Bio as well, and my edit count still seems to be consistent on there.

where do you see this edit count?

Found it! I think mine dropped as well, since I thought I was ahead of Jeromy, but that might be wishful thinking. It definitely didn't cut in half for me, though.

@ArtemKaznatcheev Yeah, I thought you were over 500 at one point (which included your own edits) and now it says 300.  I figured it might have been a policy change, but I didn't seem to lose any on Bio.

I asked one of our dev team. They told me it was cosmic rays. I'll have a fuller answer tomorrow. :)

@Aarthi Ah! Thank you.  That had totally passed under my radar.  I had checked on a few other sites and the numbers seemed to be correct, so I figured it was just us.

(no rush on the answer, btw, as long as they all didn't go 'poof' or were reversed in a landmark moderation decision :) )

@ChuckSherrington Jarrod says that 108 is the correct number. We haven't altered edit tallies whatsoever. (Copy Editor is only for title and body edits, not tags, btw.) It was totally cosmic rays, man.

@Aarthi But wiki and wiki excerpt edits count towards that, no? I have more than 108 of those alone: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/31/chuck-sherrington?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

(and now I've lost 4 more down to 104)

I should clarify that if all we are talking about is straight up edits on other people's post titles bodies, I would believe that 108 is correct, but I would swear that the count on the Users/Editors page used to reflect more than just that count -- at one point it was counting edits on one's own posts, but I think that's long changed.  I still believe that Artem and Jeromy had over 500 edits listed on Users/Editors at one point.

In the name of science, I have edited both a tag wiki and a normal post (that both needed it, of course), and they did both show up on my counts on the Users page.  The overall counts are still incorrect, though.

@josh It's more of a Users page than a profile issue (my profile seems to show the correct amounts).

@Chuck Your profile shows 308 edits. I just queried our database and you do indeed have 308 edits, but 198 of them are to your own posts, and therefore not included on the editors page.

@Emmett That can't possibly be true, I have not edited my own posts that many times.  I have edited a very large number of tag wikis/excerpts, though, which do not seem to show in that count.

Going through the list, I count only 26 edits to my own posts, reedits to tag wikis, and retags that shouldn't count.  It seems like in your query it's counting the tag wiki/excerpt edits as edits to my own posts for some reason.

@Chuck Thanks for the info -- I figured out what happened! We recently performed a database backfill to set each tag wiki "owner" as whomever provided the initial content. So in one fell swoop, you became the "owner" of a bunch of tag wikis and excerpts, and therefore your edits to them were no longer counted. We'll get our SQL query fixed up to account for this.

@Emmett Phew, I'm glad you found it!  Thanks for your diligence.

This is fixed now.
We have handful of queries that count the number of edits a user has made, while ignoring edits to their own posts. We do this for the editors page, and Archaeologist, Copy Editor, and Strunk & White badges.
A couple weeks ago, we performed a database backfill to set each tag wiki/excerpt owner as whomever provided the initial content. As a consequence, we suddenly stopped counting all of your edits to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts. The affected SQL queries have been updated to account for this.

The progress indicator (accessible via mouseover in Review) for Copy Editor is still reflecting the incorrect value.  I wasn't sure if that had to do with what Aarthi commented on above, though.

Woops, we missed that one. It will be fixed in the next build.

No worries! All seems to be working now.  Thanks!
